# Increment session variable by one

Tags: codeigniter

How the heck do I increment a variable that's inside a session?
If I declare $attempt, each time a user unsuccessfully attempts to login, I want $attempt to increase by 1. In the event it gets to 3, display a captcha.

This doesn't seem to work. :-P

```
$this->session->set_userdata('attempt',$this->attempt++);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$attempt = $this->session->userdata('attempt');
$attempt++;
$this->session->set_userdata('attempt', $attempt);
```

Comment: ah, yea, i had the "++" after the variable...which means it returns the variable and then increments it...if you do ++$attempt it should increment then return the value.

Comment: hot damn that was it! lol ... i was trying "$this->session->userdata('attempt')++ ... lol ... thx

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $visit=1;
    $view='select * from user_log where id='.$_SESSION['id'];
    $viw=mysql_query($view);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($viw)){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $visit += $row['visit'];
    $vst = $row['visit'];
    }
    if(!$_SESSION['visit']){
        $update = 'update user_log set visit='.$visit;
        mysql_query($update);                            
        $up_view = $name." you visited ".$visit;         
        $_SESSION['visit']=1;                            
        }
        else                                             
        {
            $up_view = $name." you visited ".$vst;
        }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After declaring `$this->session->userdata('attempt', 0);`
you can increment the session value using the following code.

```
$this->session->attempt++;
```